# How to use MLfLow with private git repositories?

Tags: git, gitlab, databricks, mlflow

I tested `MLflow` experiment when the source code is stored in public a git repository. Example command looks like this

```
mlflow run  https://github.com/amesar/mlflow-fun.git#examples/hello_world \
 --experiment-id=2019 \
 -Palpha=100 -Prun_origin=GitRun -Plog_artifact=True
```

However, when I provide an internal (private) git repository link instead of public- MLflow redirects to login url, and then execution fails like this.

```
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
cmdline: git fetch -v origin
stderr: 'fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
asked for: https://gitlab-master.companyname.com/myusername/project_name
/tree/master/models/myclassifier/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
redirect: https://gitlab-master.company.com/users/sign_in'
```

Is there any way to commmunicate credentials of git account to MLflow?

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide a personal access token as part of the url:

```
mlflow run https://<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>@github.com/amesar/mlflow-fun.git#examples/hello_world
```

You can generate a token here: https://github.com/settings/tokens